# Jquery Datetimepicker to Python Datetime

Tags: jquery, python, django, datetimepicker

I have below jQuery Datetimepicker

```
<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime">
```

```js
$("#datetime").datetimepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    oneLine: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```

I'm sending the date as AJAX POST request to Django:

```
const starts = $('#datetime').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/booking/new/',
    data: {
        starts: starts,
    },
};
```

In Django i get the value:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    starts = request.POST.get('starts')
    object.starts = datetime.strptime(starts, '%x %I:%M %p')
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data '11/12/2016 12:00 am' does not match format '%x %I:%M %p'

I tried different formats but I can't find the correct one. Can i produce the format from the string value some how?

Comment: Check the date format character's meanings [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks, I did and this is where i made the string for strptime function. I am trying to figure out the exact one but i couldn't so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define default datetime format like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT) follow some [rule](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date)